# How to create full height elements in a div using TailwindCSS

Tags: css, flexbox, navbar, tailwind-css

I'm having trouble because I'm newbie in CSS and flexbox.

I'm trying to create a navbar with the amazing TailwindCSS, but I need the Links vertically centered and `background-color` full height in navbar.

**What I'm doing wrong?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwindcss-navbar-sgpie

[image]

I tried `items-center` for parents and `self-center` for items, still the problem.

Answer (score 0):

please try to use your class `bg-green-400` in `<nav>` instead of `bg-white` and remove `bg-green-400` from `<a>` for more understanding please refer the below snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body class="bg-blue-600">
    <nav class="bg-green-400">
      <div class="container flex">
        <a class="bg-red-400 text-3xl p-4">Project name</a>
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <a class="p-2">Link</a>
          <a class="p-2">Link</a>
          <a class="p-2">Link</a>
          <a class="p-2">Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank You...

Comment: Oh, dear. Thanks for your answer but I used the white because I want it white!